# I can't get dictation to work on my iMac

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

I have an iMac computer running High Sierra. I want to use the dictation capability but I can't get this to work.

I have tried turning dictation off and then back on but that doesn't work. I googled this problem and found several [reports](https://appletoolbox.com/2012/08/mac-os-x-dictation-not-working-how-to-fix/) and [blogs](https://blog.pcrisk.com/mac/12670-dictation-doesnt-work-on-mac-how-to-fix) about this and most had the same things you can try to get it to work. I've followed the reports and tried their methods. Turning dictation off and restarting and turning dictation on and restarting again didn't work either.. I know my microphone is working.

Here are things I'ver tried and the problems I've encountered.

1. Turn dictation off and reboot, then turn dictation on and reboot.
2. rebooted into recovery mode and ran disk utility on my startup volume. Disk utility reported disk was fine.
3. reset Pram
4. Tried to boot into safe mode but computer hangs when doing this.
5. reinstalled High Sierra.
6. successfully booted into Safe Mode. Dictation didn't work because microphone could not be found.

Does anyone know a way to enable dictation on an iMac running High Sierra.

Comment: What exactly happens when you press fn twice ?

Comment: I hear a beep sound which I took to mean that dictation was on, but there was no response to me speaking what I wanted an app to type.

Comment: Are there any dots above the dome button which keep animating?

Comment: It would improve your chances for getting a good answer if you would tell us exactly what you've done (or are doing) to try starting dictation.

Comment: @Seamus, Thanks for your advice.  I have edited my question to show this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you booted in Safe mode and then rebooted normally?  Have you used Disk Utility to Repair Disk?  These are common quick fixes for a lot of nuisance problems.

Have you checked Sound preferences to make sure your mic is enabled?

Do you have the same problem in your bootable backup clone?

Has Dictation ever worked?  If so, what changed immediately before it stopped working?

Have you tried booting into Recovery mode and reinstalling the OS?

Comment: the mic is working.  i've used it for Facetime calls and I've sent voice texts to a friend.

Comment: I don't know if dictation has ever worked. I just tried it for the first time a few days ago.